# Vue.js: Conditional rendering based on computed property

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to conditionally render element(s) based on a computed property but not having much luck even though my computed property is returning `true` or `false` correctly.

I am passing the user object in as a property (from Laravel) and all is working fine. I am able to see the user -- and their related role(s).

I've tested via Laravel to make sure I am sending the correct user and the relationship and everything looks good there as well.

**Controller**

```
$user = User::with('roles')->find(Auth::id());
```

**blade**

```
<my-component :user="{{ $user }}"></my-component>
```

**VueComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="admin">
            <p>You are an admin!</p>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
            <p>You are not an admin.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>



<script>
export default {

    ...

    computed: {
        admin: function () {
            this.user.roles.forEach((role) => {
                console.log('role: ', role);  // role: admin (string)
                if (role.name === 'admin') {
                    console.log('user is an admin!');  // I am getting here.
                    return true;
                } else {
                    console.log('user is NOT an admin.');
                }
            });

            return false;
        },
    },
    methods: {
        //
    },
    props: {
        user: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

I'm sure I am not implementing the computed property correctly; any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `admin` nested in a `computed` object?

Comment: No, I am getting to `admin` (a user role) from the `user` object/property that is getting passed into the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is using foreach in wrong way! please use this instead:

```
  computed: {
      admin: function () {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.user.roles.length; i++){
            if ( this.user.roles[i].name === 'admin') {
                    return true;
            }
          }
          return false;
      }
   }
```

you can read this article about forEach in js https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Your mistake was return `true` from forEach `callback` function and leave this `true` value useless and then return `false` value on `admin` function.

Comment: Hi Alireza - I have it there (as you do above) I just failed to get it entered correctly in my question. I've updated to better show what I've got. My apologies & thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Hi @Damon, I've just updated my answer, hope this work!

Comment: That was it; thank you so much! I am still struggling to see what I was doing wrong. My skull must be super thick today. Should I not be using a `foreach` and instead use a "regular" `for` loop? Thank you again!

Comment: @Damon Updated.